# EverNote android-job: How can I run a job at a specific time once a day every week?

Tags: evernote, android-jobscheduler, android-job

I'm developing a weekly scheduler in android and I'm interesting in a periodic job (once a week for example) that is fired at a specific time (for example at 4.00 PM) with ***evernote android-job***

I have read this post

https://github.com/evernote/android-job/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-can-i-run-a-job-at-a-specific-time-once-a-day

and I can run a job every day once a day, but it is not my case.
If I set

`new JobRequest.Builder( MY_TAG )
    .setExact( TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis( 16 ) +  TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 0 ))
    .setPeriodic( TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis( 7 ), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5) )
    .setPersisted(true)
    .build()
    .schedule();`

I have this error

> "Can't call setExact() on a periodic job"

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

setExact() and setPeriodic() are two distinct features,they cannot be coupled.
If you want to use setExact periodically, You'd have to programatically schedule a job again once the previously set job has run.

Answer (score 0):

try this dude.

```
public final class MyDailyJob extends DailyJob {
public static final String TAG = "MyDailyJob";
public static void schedule() {
    // schedule between 1 and 6 AM
    DailyJob.schedule(new JobRequest.Builder(TAG), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(6));
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected DailyJobResult onRunDailyJob(Params params) {
    return DailyJobResult.SUCCESS;
 }
}
```

reference [link](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: Thanks, though I would suggest using proper indentation when posting code

Comment: yes, im so sorry about that @CertainPerformance, im new here. but is it wrong indentation for code?

Comment: It's not that important for something this trivial, but it looks as if the entirety of `MyDailyJob` should probably be indented (to indicate the grouped block to any reader of the code), but isn't